# A_UIViewController presentViewController B_UIViewController presentViewController UIImagePickerController dismiss A_UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, presentviewcontroller

Code in A_UIViewController:

```
PrestBViewController *aviewcontroller = [[PrestBViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:aviewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Code in B_UIViewController:

```
-(void)presentAction {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = (id)self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I run the code, it crashes at:

```
[picker.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: and what does the crash say?

Comment: Add your error log

Answer (score 0):

Code in A_viewcontroller

```
- (IBAction)PresentAction:(id)sender {
    B_ViewController *aviewcontroller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aa"];
    [self presentViewController:aviewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Code in B_viewController

```
@implementation ViewController{
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];  //Check if Camera Available
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Device has no Camera" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:ok];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }



- (IBAction)takePic:(id)sender { //Button to get image from camera
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)chooosePic:(id)sender { //Button to get image from albums
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info { //Choose image
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker { //if cancelled before selection
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Works Fine Try